# Toggle Coverage not getting collected

Tags: code-coverage, system-verilog, cadence

I am using a Coverage Configuration file to collect code coverage explicitly by mentioning "select_coverage -block -expression -toggle -module dut..."

Somehow, I am not able to get any number on toggle coverage for the dut.
I even tried using instance name instead of module, but it didn't change a thing.

These are few other settings that I have:

->select_coverage -block -expr -toggle -fsm -module dut...

->set_fsm_scoring -hold_transition

->deselect_coverage -remove_empty_instances

->deselect_coverage -expression -module A

->set_implicit_block_scoring -off

->set_expr_coverable_operators -event_or

->set_expr_coverable_statements -all

->set_libcell_scoring

->set_assign_scoring

->set_statement_scoring

->set_parameterized_module_coverage

->set_expr_scoring -struct

->set_toggle_scoring -sv_enum

->select_functional

->set_covergroup -per_instance_default_one

->set_covergroup -optimize_model

Would anyone have any idea what could possibly be stopping toggle coverage from being collected ?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of debug by examining the coverage DB in imc, I found that in an inadvertent mistake, the merge script did not pick up toggle coverage data.
The coverage was being collected fine.